# How to handle null values in gorp Select

Tags: go, gorp

I'm trying to get the users from a DB as follow,

```
var users []User
_, err := dbMap.Select(&users, "select id,username,acctstarttime,acctlastupdatedtime,acctstoptime from accounting order by id")
```

Here I'm using [gorp](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp). When there are null values present, this throws exception

```
 Select failed sql: Scan error on column index 3: unsupported driver -> Scan pair: <nil> -> *string
```

How can I solve this issue?. Here I used gorp because of the ease of mapping the output to a struct array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make whatever acctstarttime maps to a pointer to the type instead of a value of the type.

if the col is null, the pointer will be nil.

that or you can use the sql.NullXXX types, but I usually don't like those since they make everything else weird.